# How do I repair nail holes in cement board?

Tags: repair, flooring, subfloor

The transition strip between my tile bathroom floor and my carpeted bedroom floor is coming up. The nails that (should) hold the transition strip in place are nailed into what looks like concrete backer board that is installed underneath the bathroom tile. The concrete board extends about 3/8” beyond the tile. The nail holes are too close to the edge of the concrete board and as a result they have completely blown out the nail holes.

How do I fix this?

I have another transition strip and plenty of nails exactly like the ones installed. My plan is to repair the nail holes with some sort of filler material, and then install the new transition strip. Would JB Weld work as a suitable filler material? Is there another approach I could use?

Comment: What is under the backer board?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a longer nail that will go through the tile backer and into the subfloor?

Comment: It turns out there is a Plywood subfloor below the backer board. So it sounds like it would be suitable for longer nails.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any longer nails. I have plenty of 1 1/4 inch twisted brass nails, but that's the same length that was already in there. And I can't find any twisted brass nails that are longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would glue down the backboard - glue in the holes if need be too - and then install transition using longer nails/screws or just glue (liquid nails variety).